# How to change perspective in Rayshader RGL without a middle mouse button?

Tags: rgl, rayshader

I am trying to move the perspective of the rendered 3D scene in RGL after calling `plot_3d` in rayshader. I don't have a middle click on my computer, just left and right. When I open RGL using for example `plot(las)` to plot a `lidR` point cloud, I can use Shift + Right Click and drag to change perspective. However, in the RGL spawned by `plot_3d` I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: See `?rgl::par3d`, in particular the `mouseMode` entry.

Answer (score 0):

`rayshader::plot_3d` sets `rgl::par3d("mouseMode")` to

```
   none    left   right  middle   wheel 
  "none" "polar"   "fov"  "zoom"  "pull"
```

On my system (a Macbook Air with a trackpad and no mouse) I seem to have it configured so right and middle buttons are not available, but two finger drags on the trackpad are seen as mouse wheel rotation.  I also hate the `"polar"` mouse control, so if I wanted to be able to rotate the scene and also change the field of view (but lose zoom), I could change it using

```
mm <- par3d("mouseMode")
mm["left"] <- "trackball"
mm["wheel"] <- "fov"
par3d(mouseMode = mm)
```

and then clicking and dragging rotates the scene, while a two finger drag (no click necessary) changes the FOV.  Your system may map mouse modes differently, so experiment.

According to the `?rayshader::plot_3d` help page, once you have it right and have the desired settings in `mm`, you can use them for a new plot with

```
rayshader::plot_3d(..., mouseMode = mm)
```

However, the line that would implement that appears to be commented out in the source code: https://github.com/tylermorganwall/rayshader/blob/81f95cf24973049f84f4a4250daa9b0b4659281d/R/plot_3d.R#L356